# Spring Request mapping with different parameters and one same parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request

I have spring code where there is request as follows :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {
        EnterpriseLiterals.ROOT_URL_SIMPLE + "storeDepartments/search.json",
        EnterpriseLiterals.ROOT_URL_SIMPLE + "storeDepartments/search" },params = { "!dealerStoreId" })
public Map<String, List<? extends AbstractDepartment>> getDepartments(
            @RequestParam(value = "enterpriseId", required = true) String enterpriseId,@RequestParam(value = "responseFields", required = false) String responseFields)
```

And another request as :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {
        EnterpriseLiterals.ROOT_URL_SIMPLE + "storeDepartments/search",
        EnterpriseLiterals.ROOT_URL_SIMPLE + "storeDepartments/search.json" },params = {"!enterpriseId"})
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, List<AbstractDepartment>> getDepartmentListBasedOnStoreAndDeptType(@RequestParam(value = "dealerStoreId", required = true) String dealerStoreId,@RequestParam(value = "responseFields", required = false, defaultValue = "summary") String responseFields)
```

However, since there is responseFields in both the requests I am getting error when I call the above API's with responseFields saying "ResponseFields does not exist.".
Please help with solutions to solve this problem.

Comment: i think your problem is you have 2 request of same type GET with the same URL values, why do you use exactly the same name in 2 request of same type?

Comment: The responseFields are for the amount of information we get as response, and the name needs to be same across business.Hence we cannot change the name